# How to get the data received from Json to a variable for output to the site?

Tags: javascript, json

Can you please tell me how to transfer the data received from Json to a variable for output to the site?
I receive the data and output it to the page (for clarity), then it is necessary to transfer it to a variable for processing and output.
Next, the "showData()" function displays the received data on the site.
Thank you in advance!

```js
let testBox = document.querySelector('.goods .container');

// get data
function getData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => testBox.innerHTML = text)
};


// show data
let allGoods = getData(); // how to pass data to a variable?

function showData() {
    let outGoods = '';
    for (let key in allGoods) {
        outGoods += `
        <div class="goods__item">
            <a><img src="${allGoods[key].image}"/></a>
            <div class="goods__tx">
                <h2>${allGoods[key].name}</h2>
                <p>${allGoods[key].desc}</p>
                <span>${allGoods[key].availability}</span>
                <div class="goods__bottom">
                    <b>${allGoods[key].price} $</b>
                    <div class="goods__btn">
                        <button class="goods__minus" data-id="${key}">-</button>
                        <button class="goods__plus" data-id="${key}">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    }

    let goodsContent = document.querySelector('.goods .container');
    goodsContent.innerHTML = outGoods;
}
showData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/js.png" sizes="64x64">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="goods">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="cart">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="db.json"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a ‘then’ to call showData, passing it the response json (similar to how you put the response into testBox currently)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up finding a solution with an async function: codepen.io/devlogic/pen/RwJqVQO